# bcdiv minimum left/right operand

Tags: php, echo, bcmath

> echo bcdiv(0.0001, 86400, 30);

This code echos: *0.000000001157407407407407407407*

> echo bcdiv(0.00001, 86400, 30);

And this code echos: *0.000000000000000000000000000000*

Why is that? Is there a minimum value for both operands?
I need to divide 0.00000001 by 86400, is this possible?

Here's the doc for bcdiv: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bc library works with strings: don't make assumptions about its internal casting of integer arguments, but pass strings directly

```
echo bcdiv('0.00001', '86400', 30);
```

gives

```
0.000000000115740740740740740740
```